# How can I customize the sound for audible ping command?

Tags: audio, ping

Audible ping is a fine tool on network troubleshooting.
But sometimes you need to start **more than one audible ping** at the same time:

```
$ ping -a 192.168.100.5
```

and on another terminal:

```
$ ping -a 192.168.100.6
```

It could be useful to know without looking at the screen **what IP did answer** to pings, but if the sound is the same, I could not tell.

Is there any way to **specify the sound** generated by audible ping commands or temporarily change it?

Comment: Well, @dsstorefile , it seems more like a programming method, rather suited for StackOverflow, but it is at least a possible solution.

Comment: It is a possibility, @dsstorefile . With few extra software requirements, or even POSIX if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The sound is produced by the terminal when it receives a bell character, so would be difficult to change. What you can do is write a small script to read out the IP address as a number. For example, fetch the [sources tgz](http://http.debian.net/debian/pool/main/s/saytime/saytime_1.0.orig.tar.gz) to the debian `saytime` program. This is not the version using the *festival* package, but instead has its own small set of sound recordings for the numbers 0 to 9 (and more).

Unpack the tar sources, and descend to directory `saytime-1.0.orig/sounds/` and create a link from file `oh.au` to `0.au`.  You can then ping something, without `-a` but with an interval of at least 2 seconds and pipe the output into an awk script that runs `aplay` (part of package `alsa-utils`) to speak the last number of the IP address:

```
cd saytime-1.0.orig/sounds
ln -sf oh.au 0.au
ping -i 2 192.168.0.254 |
stdbuf -oL awk '
/ from /{split($4,x,".")
        f = "aplay -q -f mu_law "
        for(i=1;i<length(x[4]);i++)f = f " " substr(x[4],i,1)".au"
        print f }' |
sh -x
```